# Query two similar tables and combine sorted results

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have three tables

```
orders.orderid (and other non-pertinent stuff)

payment.orderid
payment.transactiondate
payment.amount

projectedpayment.orderid
projectedpayment.projecteddate
projectedpayment.projectedamount
```

Essentially, `payment` represents when actual payments are received; `projectedpayment` represents when the system thinks they should be received. I need to build a query to compare projected vs actual.

I'd like to query them such that each row in the query has the orderid, payment.transactiondate, payment.amount, projectedpayment.projecteddate, projectedpayment.projectedamount, with the rows from payment and projectedpayment sorted by their respective dates. e.g.,

```
orderid transactiondate amount projecteddate projectedamount
      1      2015-01-01  12.34    2015-01-03           12.34
      1      2015-01-15  12.34    2015-01-15           12.44
      1            null   null    2015-02-01           12.34
      2      2014-12-31  50.00          null            null
```

So broken down by order, what are the actual and projected payments, where there may be more projected payments than actual, or more actual payments than projected, aligned by date (simply by sorting the two, nothing more complex than that).

It seems like I should be able to achieve this with a `left join` from `orders` to some kind of `union` of the other two tables sorted with an `order by`, but I haven't been able to make it work, so it may be something completely different. I know I cannot join all three of `order`, `payment`, and `projectedpayment` or I get the cross-product of the latter two tables.

I happen to be using `postgresql` 9.4, but hopefully we don't need to get too database-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know postgres sorry :( but if you know how to do partitioned row numbers something like this should work.

```
select
    coalesce(a.orderid,b.orderid) as orderid
    ,transactiondate
    ,amount
    ,projecteddate
    ,projectedamount
FROM

        (select
            orderid
            ,ransactiondate
            ,amount
            ,row_number() over (partition by orderid order by orderid,transactiondate) as rn
        from payment) as a

        full join 
        (select
            orderid
            ,projecteddate
            ,projectedamount
            ,row_number() over (partition by orderid order by orderid,projecteddate) as rn
        from projectedpayment) as b

        on a.orderid= b.orderid
        and a.rn = b.rn
```

*this is sqlserver syntax (2K5+ AFAIK)

The logic here is that you need to assign a unique number to each predicted and actual payment so that you can join the two tables together but only have each row matching a single row from the other table.

If you have *ONLY ONE PAYMENT PER DAY* then yo could do the full join on the order ID and date without worrying about row numbers.

the full join allows you to have nulls on either side so you will need to coalesce orderid

*also this doesn't show orders with NO payments or predictions.. comment if this is an issue.

Comment: Thanks! The `full join` combined with the `row_number()..over()` is a clever way to solve this problem that I've never seen before.

Comment: I do a lot of data migration / master data / data review work and techniques like this are life savers :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Select * from Orders o
Left Join Payments p on o.ID = p.OrderID
Left Join ProjectedPaymentp pp on o.ID = pp.OrderID
Order By o.ID
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for.  This will have a record for every `Payment` against every `ProjectedPayment` for an `Order`.  That is, if you have four `Payments` for one `Order`, and say 4 `ProjectedPayments`, one for each month, you will get 16 records for that one `OrderId`.  I **believe** the OP wants the `ProjectedPayments` to somehow be limited by the closest `timestamp`... if any of that makes sense :)

Comment: No u will not get 16 record. Look at join closely. I dont join Payments on ProjectedPaymentp . I join them both on Products

Comment: But I want four rows, in this example. Or, more generally `max(count(payment.*), count(projectedpayment.*))` rows for a given order.

Comment: Here is your query in a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b2c5/1) -- notice the 16 records for OrderId 1 (that's with 4 payments and 4 projectedpayments).  Either way, it's not the answer to the question

Comment: @koehn yes u will get exactly max(count(payment.*), count(projectedpayment.*)) count of rows. I have modifide comment. 8 rows was mistake

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand, the following query should help:

```
select o.orderid, ap.transactiondate, ap.amount, pp.projecteddate, pp.projectedamount
from orders o
left join
(
    select p.orderid, p.transactiondate, p.amount,
        row_number() over (partition by p.orderid order by p.transactiondate) n
    from payment p    
) ap on o.orderid = ap.order
left join
(
    select p.orderid, p.projecteddate, p.projectedamount,
        row_number() over (partition by p.orderid order by p.projecteddate) n
    from projectedpayment p  
) pp on o.orderid = ap.order and (ap.n is null or ap.n = pp.n)
order by o.orderid, ap.n, pp.n
```

**UPD**
Another option (works in slightly different way and you can have `NULL` values not only for last records for same `orderid` but it will be completely sorted by date, in one timeline):

```
select o.orderid, ap.transactiondate, ap.amount, pp.projecteddate, pp.projectedamount
from orders o
inner join
(
    select ap.orderid, ap.transactiondate d from payment ap 
    union   
    select ap.orderid, ap.projecteddate d from projectedpayment pp
) d on d.orderid = o.orderid
left join payment ap on ap.orderid = o.orderid and ap.transactiondate = d.d
left join projectedpayment pp on pp.orderid = o.orderid and pp.projecteddate = d.d
order by o.orderid, d.d
```

Comment: does this not have issues if there are more projected payments than actuals?

Comment: Good point. I fixed condition to work if there is projected payment but there is no actual payment with the same number

Comment: do you not need ot force there to be a row with o.orderid not null and p.n is null to allow third table to join to it? sorry i am curious as i have not used this technique before and its interesting

Comment: o.orderid can not be null. It's from orders table. But ap.n can be null if there is no actual payment with same number as projected payment.

Comment: yep.. what i mean is if you have 1 payment but 5 projected ones then you wont have a row with an orderid but null in ap.n for the projected payments to join to.. not sure i am explaining that very well. note also on option two that if you have more than one payment per day that would have issues i think.

Comment: May be I don't understand you.. But as I see in the original question there are both cases: with null-s in projected and in actual columns. What is exact required ordering isn't perfectly clear so I think it would be better to test all queries in the big amount of source data and analyze which result is correct. Or to more strictly define ordering conditions.

Comment: Agreed on the testing for this type of thing! if there is 1 payment then orders left outer join payments will have one row and ap.n will not be null.  if you then have 2 projected payments there will be nothing for the second row to join to as there is no row where ap.n is null. (unless i have something wrong here).. i have never done the chat thing before but SO doesn't want us to continue here :D